# Cordova camera plugin always return the same image when select from gallery with file URI

Tags: javascript, cordova

After upgrading to the latest cordova camera lib 0.3.4, I am able to get the real image uri after selecting an image from gallery, the returned file call pic.jpg, however if I select another one, it will return the same image with the same name pic.jpg, so I am stuck with the same image :(

the image path looks like file:///storage/emulated/0/android/data/app/cache/.pic.jpg

Any idea?

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/src/android/CameraLauncher.java

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture($scope.processImageUri, $scope.onFail, {
            quality: 88,
            correctOrientation: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: true
        });
```

Comment: having the same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Also having the same problem. Would love to hear your solution if you have one.

Comment: Try to update the camera plugin, I think this is fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write these code after your function and replace your "destinationType:" with mine

```js
  function capturePhoto()
 {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }
```

Comment: You should write onPhotoDataSuccess

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/#cameradestinationtype--enum) "DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILEURI or NATIVE_URI if possible"

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this issue on iOS platform (iOS 10.2). I didn't want to use accepted solution of moving to DATA_URI because I am using same code between iOS and Android and wanted to keep FILE_URI approach only.

Started debugging and found that it happens because of calling cleanup function after getting picture. Since in cleanup call file is removed from temporary storage, plugin gives same filename to next picture being available. Logically that should be fine, but here web view playing an evil, picks old image from its cache as URL is same as pervious.

I came with a small fix. Tested that and in my case it worked fine.

I have [forked the camera plugin](https://github.com/klodha/cordova-plugin-camera/commit/f445f8bc8e1675bd9c47c8dc36cfb82fd3e5002e) repo and modified method generating temporary file name.

I missed the guideline for parent repository and my commit isn't in required format so I guess my pull request will be declined. (I will update & recreate it as I get some time).

But for now, unless you are planning to remove/add platform (which might clone from master repo loosing the change) you can try this solution.

Comment: Well done. Thanks for this - saved me some debugging! I've managed to patch this within JS adding a timestamp to the Image URI returned from the plugin like this; imageURI += '?' + +new Date(); - works fine and still allows me to use the current master.

Comment: Smart way. I thought about it, but then I wanted to propose this fix in plugin itself, so modified it. Unfortunately, so far no word on my pull request.